# WordPress - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_VERSION"

Tags: php, wordpress

I just moved my wordpress site from a server to my localhost to make some changes.
The websites on the server works great. But when i run it on localhost i get this.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_VERSION" in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-content/plugins/modeltheme-framework/inc/sb-google-
maps-vc-addon/sb-google-maps-vc-addon.php:3 Stack trace: #0 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-content/plugins/modeltheme-framework/modeltheme-
framework.php(65): require_once() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-settings.php(409):
 include_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-config.php(90): 
require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-load.php(50): 
require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-blog-
header.php(13): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #5 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/index.php(17): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #6 {main} 
thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-content/plugins/modeltheme-framework/inc/sb-
google-maps-vc-addon/sb-google-maps-vc-addon.php on line 3




Notice: is_embed was called incorrectly. The conditional functions do not work before the 
query is executed. Before the basic application they give false. Please see the Debugging 
in WordPress page for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) In 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5535


Notice: is_search was called incorrectly. The conditional functions do not work before 
the query is executed. Before the basic application they give false. Please see the 
Debugging in WordPress page for more information. (This message was added in version 
3.1.0.) In /opt/lampp/htdocs/cruiceWP/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5535
```

This is the file that has the problem as the error message says.
**sb-google-maps-vc-addon.php**

```
<?php

@define(SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_VERSION,'1.4');                                                 //Plugin Version
@define(SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_NAME, 'MT Google Maps');                    //Plugin Name
@define(SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_DIR, trim(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__), '/'));                          //Plugin Dir
@define(SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_PATH, trim(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__), '/'));                        //Plugin Path

//Including all common functions
include('inc/functions.php');

//Including admin panel
include('admin/admin-panel.php');

//Including shortcodes
include('shortcodes.php');
```

Im stuck for days in this. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

PHP constant names need to be defined as strings. Prior to PHP 8, if you passed an unquoted string, PHP would raise a warning but still treat it as a string which is why that developer included the silencing `@` operator.

The fix is to quote the names, and I’d remove the `@`, too

```php
define('SBVCGMAP_PLUGIN_VERSION','1.4');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the ```@``` and quoted the names. This seem to solved the problem, but i got lot of warning on my  website

Comment: Your main host appears to be PHP 7.4 or less, and doesn’t have warnings on, whereas your local host is PHP 8 with warnings on. There are many WordPress themes and plugins that aren’t ready for 8, and even if they are, if you purchased them, you might have to pay for a new version. You could try staying at a lower PHP version. Otherwise, for each of the problems you run into, you can ask a new question here.